# Empty ListView when EditText is empty

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-edittext

I have code which takes data from SQLite cursor and puts into listview.

```
private void displayListView() {
    cursor = myDatabase.getJoinedInfo(etSearch.getText().toString().trim());

    String[] columns = new String[] { "re_value", "g_value", "ke_value" };

    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvHiragana, R.id.tvMeaning, R.id.tvKanji };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.wordonlist,
            cursor, columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvWordlist);
    // Assign adapter to ListView

    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

When EditText is empty, it is taking first 10 lines. How to show empty ListView when EditText is empty?

Comment: explain properly your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this :

```
If(yourEditText.length() == 0)
    yourListView.setAdapter(null);
```

Or you can use :

```
If(yourEditText.length() == 0)
    yourAdapter.clear();
```

Comment: tried to implement in setOnKeyListener: etSearch.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() { public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { if (etSearch.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1) { listView.setAdapter(null); } if (keyCode == 66) { hideKeyboard(v); return true; } return false; } }); But it is very slow...

Comment: I think you want to add search functionality in listview, Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

do not set the adapter until EditText is empty. You can set the adapter after there's some data in EditText.

Comment: When application start, everything is ok. It is not showing nothing. But when added and deleted letters in EditText, ListView with first 10 lines remains. I want to make it empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void displayListView() {
    if (etSearch.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
        listView.setAdapter(null);
    } else {
        cursor = myDatabase.getJoinedInfo(etSearch.getText().toString()
                .trim());

        String[] columns = new String[] { "re_value", "g_value", "ke_value" };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvHiragana, R.id.tvMeaning,
                R.id.tvKanji };

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.wordonlist,
                cursor, columns, to, 0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvWordlist);
        // Assign adapter to ListView

        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is here, i'm calling displayListView() method on onTextChanged inside TextWatcher which doesn't work when EditText is empty.

Comment: tried to implement in setOnKeyListener: etSearch.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (etSearch.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1) {
     listView.setAdapter(null);
    }
    if (keyCode == 66) {
     hideKeyboard(v);
     return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
  });